# Find the pattern

Tags: geometry, visual

Let's start with an easy one. Find the logic behind the positions of the squares inside the circles. An explanation is sufficient, no need to draw. The answer is not three in a row.

[image]

BTW there must be more visual puzzles considering non English speakers.

Comment: You may be interested in the books "Without Words", and "More Without Words", two books by James Stanton, and printed by Tarquin Press. They contain visual mathematical puzzles similar to yours.  http://www.tarquingroup.com/product.php?SKU_Code=2276

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are

> the best packings of squares into circles.

The answer is :

> [image]

You can see the first 35 members of this pattern [here](https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/squincir/).

Comment: That was really fast and thank you for the link,

Comment: It's interesting how asymmetric a lot of these are.